# Google App Engine - Datastore get_or_insert key_name confusion

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, key

I am confused by `get_or_insert(..)`. What should I pass as the `key_name`? Consider the following example:

```
class Person(db.model)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Assume that no two people can have the same name. Say I want to get or insert a new `Person` with name `Peter`, what would my `get_or_insert` statement look like?

Cheers,

Pete

Comment: are you aware that the declared db.StringProperty name has nothing to do with key_name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The possibly confusing thing here is that the key doesn't show up directly in your model declaration, so that `name = db.StringProperty` bit in your example isn't needed. `get_or_insert` takes the keyname as its first (required) argument, so you're looking for code like:

```
person = Person.get_or_insert('Peter')
# other interesting & useful code here...
# later, maybe we need to retrieve that key name from the object:
name = person.key().name()
assert(name == "Peter")
```

Comment: Yes, but the key name being set here is a permanent, unique identifier for the entity, rather than a mutable property inside the entity body. The "name" property in your model declaration is unused in the example above.

Comment: I get the error TypeError: 'Key' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

You can think of `key_name` like a primary key.  Look at the docs for [`get_or_insert(...)`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_or_insert), there is an example of what the back-end code looks like.

If name is a unique field, you might want to use that as the key name too.  Although I would suggest stripping white-space and normalizing case.