# App engine model, get_or_insert question w.r.t primary key and composite keys

Tags: python, google-app-engine

**A] Summary of the problem:**

I Have 1 to many hierarchical relationships between models

Country (1) --> City (Many)
City (1) --> Status (Many)

So, there can only be one unique country, a country can only have one unique city, and a city could have many statuses

I am planning to use "get_or_insert" method to make sure that i maintain unique records in the database.

**B] Code Excerpts:**

*1] Model structure --*

```
class UserReportedCountry(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class UserReportedCity(db.Model):
  country = db.ReferenceProperty(UserReportedCountry, collection_name='cities')
  name = db.StringProperty(required=True)   

class UserReportedStatus(db.Model):
  city = db.ReferenceProperty(UserReportedCity, collection_name='statuses')
  status = db.BooleanProperty()
  date_time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

*2] Code that is used for storing the data retrieved from the HTML form:*

```
def store_user_data(self): 
  country_name = self.request.get('selCountry')
  user_reported_country = UserReportedCountry.get_or_insert(name=country_name)

  user_reported_city =  UserReportedCity.get_or_insert( name = self.request.get('city'), country = user_reported_country )

  user_reported_status = UserReportedStatus( status = self.request.get('status'), city = user_reported_city)
    user_reported_status.put()
```

**Questions:**

1] From the google search, it appears "get_or_insert" requires a key, In my case in the "UserReportedCountry" model, i want the name of the country to be the primary key
and in the "UserReportedCity" model, i want the combination of country name + city name to be the key. How do i go about doing this ?

2] Is there a way to use "get_or_insert" without specifying a key, I came accross the following posting on stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308002/google-app-engine-datastore-get-or-insert-key-name-confusion), and tried the idea but it didnt work.

Thank you for reading,

**[EDIT#1]**

Summary of the changes based on the response given by @Josh Smeaton

1] Now the code checks if the user reported country is present in the db or not. If the user reported country is not present, then the code creates a UserReportedCountry, UserReportedCity and attaches a new status to it

2] If the country is present, then the code checks whether the user reported city is present for the given country.

If the city is not found, then create a city record and associated it with the found country and attach a status record.

If the city is found, then attach the status record to it.

**Request:**

I will highly appreciate, If someone can please do a code review and let me know if i am making any mistakes.

Thanks,

Code excerpts:

```
#this method will be used to parse the data the user provided in the html form and store it in the database models
#while maintaing the relationship between UserReportedCountry, UserReportedCity and UserReportedStatus
#BUG, there needs to be error checking to make sure the country , city and status data is invalid or not
#if the data is invalid, then error message needs to be reported and then redirection back to the main page
def store_user_data(self):
    #method call to find out the completly filled out UserReportedCity model
    user_reported_city = self.find_or_create_user_reported_country_and_city(
                                self.request.get('selCountry'), self.request.get('city'))

    #status is always unique for a user entry, so create a brand new UserReportedStatus everytime.
    user_reported_status = UserReportedStatus(status = self.get_user_reported_status(), city = user_reported_city)
    user_reported_status.put()            

#Here the code needs to find out if there is an existing country/city for the user selection
#1] If the user reported country doesnt exist, create a new country record, create a new city record and return the city record
#2] If the user reported country exists, check if the user reported city is associated with the country. 
#if the city exists, then return it. If the city doesnt exists, then create a new city and return it  
#example: if the user chooses USA, there needs to be a check if USA is already present or not, 
#so that we dont create an additonal USA record
def find_or_create_user_reported_country_and_city(self, country_name, city_name):
    country_query_result = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM UserReportedCountry WHERE name = :country_name_value" 
                                       ,country_name_value = country_name).get()

    if (country_query_result == None):
        #since the country doesnt exists, create and save the country
        user_reported_country = self.create_and_save_user_country_record(country_name)

        #Since the country doesnt exist, there cannot be a city record for the given country, so blindly create the record
        return self.create_and_save_user_city_record(city_name, user_reported_country)
    else:
        #Since we found a country, now we need to find whether the user selected city exists for the given country
        return self.find_or_create_city_for_country(country_query_result, city_name)

#Check wheter the user selectred city exists in the country
#1] if the city exists return the record back 
#2] if the city doesnt exist creaty the city record and return it   
def find_or_create_city_for_country(self, country_record, city_name):
    city_query_result = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM UserReportedCity WHERE name = :city_name_value AND country =:country_value"
                                     ,city_name_value = city_name, country_value = country_record ).get()

    if (city_query_result == None):
        #Since the city doesnt exist for the given country, 
        #create the city record, associated it with the country and return the record back
        return self.create_and_save_user_city_record(city_name, country_record)
    else:
        #since the city was found, return the record back 
        return city_query_result    

#method to create a UserReportedCountry record for a given country name 
def create_and_save_user_country_record(self, country_name):
    user_reported_country = UserReportedCountry(name= country_name)
    user_reported_country.put()
    return user_reported_country

#method to create a UserReportedCity record for a given city name and a given country record
def create_and_save_user_city_record (self, city_name, country_record):
    user_reported_city = UserReportedCity(name = city_name, country = country_record)
    user_reported_city.put()
    return user_reported_city
```

[EDIT#2]

Inside the html form, the call to save the data is done using "post". Do you think this is still a problem?

```
<div id="userDataForm">
    <form method="post" action="/UserReporting">
      <p> Select Country: </p>
      <select name="selCountry" id="country">
      <!-- By default, we will select users country -->
      <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            document.write("<option value=\"" + geoip_country_name() + "\" selected>"
      </script>
      :
      :
      :
      <p> Select City: </p>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city"> 

        <!-- By default, we will select users city -->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            document.getElementById("city").value = geoip_city()
        </script>

      </div>    

      <input type="submit" name="report_down" value="Report Down">
      <input type="submit" name="report_up" value="Report Up"> 
    </form>
<div>
```

Initially i tried using the Djangoforms, but i got blocked because i didnt knew how to use javascript to select a value in the djangoform

Comment: You appear to be breaking one of the cardinal rules of HTTP. A GET should NEVER perform a destructive operation (INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE). A POST HTTP method should be used instead. You should use a form, and wrap all this implementation detail in the form you create. I'm not familiar with GAE, only Django, so the following post may help. http://jamesgae.appspot.com/blog/2010/01/08/using-django-forms-on-app-engine

Comment: The reason being, a script could be created to hit your site thousands of times with gibberish in the query params, totally messing up your data. With a form, (with CSRF protection), you can severely hamper potential attackers.

Comment: @Josh Smeaton, Inside the html form, the call to save the data is done using "post", please refer to "EDIT#2" in my original post for the code. Do you think the code is still having issue?. 

I initially used djangoform, but i wanted to select the users country and city value by default, but i got blocked because i didnt knew how to use javascript to select a value in the djangoform
I am very new to this framework, so my questions might be silly :(

Comment: Your subject says 'django', but these are App Engine models, not Django ones.

Comment: @Nick Johnson, i removed the django-model tag from the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address your questions in order:

> 1] From the google search, it appears
>   "get_or_insert" requires a key, In my
>   case in the "UserReportedCountry"
>   model, i want the name of the country
>   to be the primary key and in the
>   "UserReportedCity" model, i want the
>   combination of country name + city
>   name to be the key. How do i go about
>   doing this ?

Simply specify the name of the country, and the concatenation of country and city (eg "USA/San Francisco" as the key names you pass to `get_or_insert`. As an aside, `get_or_insert` is simply syntactic sugar for the following:

```
def get_or_insert(cls, key_name, **kwargs):
  def _tx():
    obj = cls.get_by_key_name(key_name)
    if obj is None:
      return cls(key_name, **kwargs)
    else:
      return obj
  return db.run_in_transaction(_tx)
```

> 2] Is there a way to use
>   "get_or_insert" without specifying a
>   key, I came accross the following
>   posting on stackoverflow
>   (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308002/google-app-engine-datastore-get-or-insert-key-name-confusion),
>   and tried the idea but it didnt work.

It doesn't really make sense to do so. The key is the only unique field for a model in App Engine, and you can't do cross-entity-group queries in App Engine, so unless you specify one it's not possible to do a transactional get-or-insert operation. Given your requirements, though, using country name and city name as key names ought to work just fine.

Comment: Thank you @Nick Johnson, I will try this approach tonight and let you know the results. Using this approach, do i still have to worry about the CSRF issue mentioned by @Josh Smeaton?

Comment: @lance Yes, you do - my answer only shows you how to use the datastore in the fashion you want. You still need to ensure you build your webapp securely.

Comment: So, the only way to avoid CSRF is to use Django forms and not write my own form in html ?, also to not have the whole code for doing get and insert and instead use the "get_or_insert" functionality provided by google?. Sorry if i am being naive, i am new to this and dont want to go in the wrong direction.

Comment: @lance There's many ways to avoid CSRF - Django provides just one way; other frameworks provide others. The main issue originally identified with your code is that you're making changes based on a GET request, though - GET requests are supposed to be idempotent. If you want to get into this further, you should do some research and ask another question if you're still unclear.

Comment: Thank you @Nick Johnson, at this point i have decided to implement Djangoforms using the link http://jamesgae.appspot.com/blog/2010/01/08/using-django-forms-on-app-engine, provided by @Josh Smeaton. Thank you again to both @Nick Johnson and @Josh Smeaton for your patience and help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if GAE utilizes the inner Meta class, but in django, I'd make use of the `unique` field parameter for the country name for the Country definition, and `unique_together` Meta tuple for `('country', 'name') in the City definition. This will enforce the integrity in any case that you happen to forget the get_or_insert correct incantation.

Otherwise, do a lookup on the name (the get operation), and if it doesn't yet exist, do the insert. Basically, mimic the get_or_insert in your own code.

Comment: @Josh Smeaton, Based on your suggestion of doing a manually check on the country , city name and their relationship prior to adding entries in the d/b, i have made changes that are present in the "[EDIT#1]" section of the submission.

Comment: @Nick, the first or second idea?

Comment: I agree with @Nick Johnson, i searched for unique in google models but couldnt find any entries, and hence choose to write the entire code to implement get or insert functionality.

Comment: @lance, Nick has a better answer that specifically answers your use case regarding GAE - you should probably accept his answer =P

Comment: Thank you @Josh Smeaton for your help. I have selected his answer. I have read the link that you have provided and implementing djangoforms in my model.