# How to have composite ID for NDB datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Previously, I have the following entity

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required = True)
```

I use `name` as id, by written my code in the following way

```
user = User.get_or_insert(name, name=name, 
    timestamp=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(user_timestamp))
```

**By having `name` as id, I can perform fast read or update using `name`.**

---

Now, I decide to change my entity to the following, and have both `name` and `type` as composite id.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    type = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required = True)
```

After referring https://stackoverflow.com/a/5454623/72437

My first thought is, by concatenation both `name` and `type`, it achieve my composite id purpose.

```
user = User.get_or_insert(name+type, name=name, type=type
    timestamp=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(user_timestamp))
```

Soon, I realize this idea is flaw. As the following situation will create conflicting.

```
name    type    id 
-------------------------   
cheok   paid    cheokpaid
cheokp  aid     cheokpaid
```

2 different users end up with same id.

**I was wondering, what is the proper way for me**

1. To have composite id based on `name` and `type`
2. Have fast read or update, using `name` and `type`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use a separator while concatenating name and type. Then your code will work as is and solve your problem.

For example if you use '_' as your separator then

```
cheok   paid  become cheok_paid   and
cheokp  aid   become cheokp_aid
```

Comment: How about `{number of characters in name}_ + name + "_" + type`.  You could also concatenate at end.  By splitting at "_", you can get index of end of name.

Comment: @GAEfan just curious, what's the point of "number of characters in name" with `id = “{}_{}_{}”.format(len(name), name, type)`?

Comment: OP mentioned the issue with user having a trailing underscore in `name` or leading underscore in `type`, thus making the underscore separator unusable (can't distinguish between `"name_" + "_" + "type"` and `"name" + "_" + "_type"`.  The num_characters lets the OP know where the separation is between `name` and `type`.  I still added the underscore separator for readability.  (I see OP has now deleted that objection.)